# How is .call supposed to work for ES6 Arrow Functions (according to the standards)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using a cross-compiler (Babel, soon to be TypeScript) for ES6 and it currently does not support proper `.call` behavior for functions made with the => syntax; when I call them with `.call`, their `this` value is still the one they inherited from the parent scope when I first made them, instead of being the first argument I passed in with `.call`.

Is this their intentional behavior, as per the ES6 standards (which would be very disappointing)? Or is this just a limitation of the cross-compiler?

Comment: The whole point of arrow functions is that they inherit their `this` from their parent lexical environment. Allowing `this` to be set from the caller would break that and defeat the purpose of having them in the first place.

Comment: It's not like normal ES5 lambda functions don't have a default value for this as well (the Window variable). If that one can be overwritten with .call, why can't arrow functions have their this be overwritten similarly?

Comment: It's easiest to think of is as if their `this` has already been set with `.bind`, so even if you use `.call` after, it has no affect because the `this` was already specified.

Comment: I don't really understand why the browser couldn't easily implement behavior so that .call overrules .bind either. Is there an actual speed concern if browsers supported such behavior?

Comment: If `.bind` could be overridden, then there wouldn't be a point in having it. The fact that you want this behavior says to me that you should be using a normal function instead. The key thing here is that arrow functions are not a replacement for normal functions, both have their uses.

Comment: There is a small portion of the time where I have functions that want an inherited, but also overwriteable `this`, but admittedly a lot of the times it was to save 10 characters and a newline.

Comment: If you want to control the value of `this`, don't use an arrow function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) says:

> An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for arguments, super,
>   this, or new.target. **Any reference to arguments, super, this, or
>   new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a
>   lexically enclosing environment.**

I.e. it's fixed to the context in where it was defined. You can't dynamically change it. Specifically on [Function.prototype.call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.call) it says:

> If func is an arrow function or a bound function then the thisArg will
>   be ignored by the function [[Call]] in step 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function like `methodical` bellow it will create a method where `this` is passed in as the first argument of the callback. That way you have all the benefits of the fat arrow syntax (implicit return, `this` not being lost on subsequent function calls) but still being able to use it as a method. Of course there is also the short-hand method syntax which is basically creates a traditional es5 style function (slightly different as it can't be called with new).

```js
const methodical = func => function(...args) {
  return func(this, ...args)
}

const add = methodical(
  (instance, name, value) => (instance[name] = value, instance)
)

const a = {
  add
}

a.add('first', 1.23).add('second', 2.74)

add.call(a,'third', 3.11)
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2))
```

using es2015 shorthand methods instead

```js
const b = {
  add(name,value) {
    this[name] = value
    return this
  }
}
b.add('first',1).add('second',2)
console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
```